# Generate Sphere of Cubes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm trying to generate a sphere by instantiating cubes. This might sound like an easy task for a beginner - I'm being ironic, of course - but I found sort of an example at: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html -- except that it's only a circle:

[image: Circle of Cubes]

Ideally I'd like the generator/code to also transform the cubes to that they are laid out side by side (with no spacing; or a configurable spacing), and with multiple rows so that they form a solid sphere. So I think that the code needs to transform both the outer and inner faces of the cube.

How can this be done? Here's the code for the circle:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class CubeSphere : MonoBehaviour {
    // Instantiates prefabs in a circle formation
    public GameObject prefab;
    public int numberOfObjects = 4;
    public float radius = 5f;
    void Start() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
            float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2 / numberOfObjects;
            float x = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;
            float z = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;
            Vector3 pos = transform.position + new Vector3(x, 0, z);
            float angleDegrees = -angle * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, angleDegrees, 0);
            Instantiate(prefab, pos, rot);
        }
    }
}
```

**Bonus question**: Is it also possible to curve the prefabs (like a curved screen), resulting in a really smooth sphere of prefabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a point (Vector3) to be the center. Let's call **c**.

Define a distance (float) to be the length of the radius. Call it **R**.

Imagine a vertical line through **c** with length **2R**:

```
| \
|  )R
| /
c
| \
|  )R
| /
```

A sphere is nothing but a lot of circunferences, one below the other:

```
      --|--        circunference 1
   -----|-----     circunference 2
 -------|-------   circunference 3
--------c--------  circunference 4
 -------|-------   circunference 5
   -----|-----     circunference 6
      --|--        circunference 7
```

Now you need to define how many circunferences you will want in your sphere, the more you have, the better it will look (and the heavier too). In this example, we are using 7 circunferences. We should have the position (in y-axis) for each of them, it's easy to evaluate.

How to evaluate the radius of any of these circunferences? Let's see an example evaluating the radius of circunference 1:

```
     .--|--                     .--|     by definition, we have this
   ---\-|-----                  |\ | h   height h (it is not c.y + R, 
 ------\|-------                | \|     is something below that)
--------c--------  =>           '--c    
 -------|-------                 x
   -----|-----     
      --|--
```

We know that `cos(angle) = h / R`, so we evaluate angle as `angle = arccos(h / R)`.

The radius **x** should be `R * sin(angle)`.

---

The last step is to decide how many cubes you should instantiate in each circunference. You can decide based on the length of the circunference (2πr). You can just suppose that for some length **L**, there will be one cube, so for any length 2πr, there should be 2πr/**L** cubes. The positions of each cube you can easily evaluate:

Suppose for circunference 1 of radius **r**, 2πr/**L** = 3, so we'll have 3 cubes:

```
 ^         _.----[2]                 ^
 |       .'         '.               |          [][][]    circunference 1
 |      /             \              |        [][][][][]
z|    [1]      c       |            y|      [][][][][][][]     ...
 |      \             /              |        [][][][][]
 |       '.         .'               |          [][][]    curcunference 7
 |         ''----[3]                 |
 |---------------------------->      |---------------------------->
               x                                  x
```

Obviously, the smaller you define **L**, more cubes there will be and better it will look.

Comment: Thank you! This will surely help me in the right direction!!

Answer (score 2):

Found a script from one of the tutorials on youtube.

### Script: VoxelTools.cs

```
﻿using UnityEngine;
﻿using System.Collections;
﻿using System.Collections.Generic;

﻿public class VoxelTools : MonoBehaviour
﻿{
﻿
   ﻿ private static GameObject cubePrefab;
﻿    private static GameObject cubeContainer;
﻿    private static int cubeCount = 0;
    ﻿private static List<GameObject> cubes;

﻿    public static Color GetRandomColor()
    ﻿{
        ﻿float r = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
﻿        float g = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
    ﻿    float b = Random.Range(0f, 1f);

        ﻿//make grey/sludge colors less likely
﻿        for (int i = 0; i < Random.Range(1, 3); i++)
        ﻿﻿    {
            ﻿if (Random.Range(0, 10) > 1)
            ﻿{
                ﻿int a = Random.Range(0, 3);
﻿                if (a == 0)
    ﻿                r = 0;
        ﻿        if (a == 1)
            ﻿        g = 0;
                ﻿if (a == 2)
                    ﻿b = 0;
﻿            }
    ﻿    }

        ﻿return new Color(r, g, b);
﻿    }

    ﻿public static GameObject MakeCube(float x, float y, float z)
﻿    {
    ﻿    return MakeCube(x, y, z, Color.red, 1);
    ﻿}

﻿    public static GameObject MakeCube(float x, float y, float z, Color color)
    ﻿{
        ﻿return MakeCube(x, y, z, color, 1);
﻿    }

    ﻿public static GameObject MakeCube(float x, float y, float z, Color color, float size)
﻿    {
    ﻿    return MakeCube(new Vector3(x, y, z), color, size);
﻿    }

    ﻿private static GameObject GetCubePrefab()
﻿    {    ﻿
    ﻿    if (cubePrefab == null)
        ﻿    cubePrefab = Resources.Load("Cube") as GameObject;
        ﻿return cubePrefab;
﻿    }

public static GameObject MakeCube(Vector3 position, Color color, float size)
{
    cubeCount++;
    if (cubeContainer == null)
    {
        cubeContainer = new GameObject("cube container");
        cubes = new List<GameObject>();
    }

    GameObject cube = Instantiate(GetCubePrefab()) as GameObject;
    cubes.Add(cube);
    cube.transform.position = position;
    cube.transform.parent = cubeContainer.transform;
    cube.name = "cube " + cubeCount;

    cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = color;
    cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(size, size, size);

    return cube;
}

﻿    public static void MakeAllCubesFall()
    ﻿{
﻿        foreach (GameObject cube in cubes)
            ﻿if (cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() == null)
        ﻿        cube.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
    ﻿}
﻿}
```

### Result:

[image]

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you! But shouldn’t there be a Start() method (or sort of) that does the acctual layout? I can’t seem to find the math part in this...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUMYRgwOmO8

here is the source video. 

Instructor credits: http://www.codingplayground.ca

Comment: `VoxelTools.cs` is not the script that makes the makes this, it's just a helper class that handles the spawning of the cubes. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the VoxelTools.cs provided in the other answer:

```
public void CreateSphere(int r, Vector3 center) {
    int r2 = r*r;
    for (int x = -r; x <= r; ++x)
        for (int y = -r; y <= r; ++y)
            for (int z = -r; z <= r; ++z)
                if (new Vector3(x,y,z).sqrMagnitude <= r2)
                    VoxelTools.MakeCube(center.x + x, center.y + y, center.z +z);
}
```